# How can i loop through a group of check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```
var days = ['daily', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'];
```

these are my check box. Every check box have unique id. backup_freq_daily,backup_freq_monday, etc. Whenever i click on daily ,or monday or thu or thu etc, i need to do some operation.

```
$('#bm_freq_daily,#bm_freq_mon,#bm_freq_tues,#bm_freq_weds,#bm_freq_thur,#bm_freq_fri,#bm_freq_sat,#bm_freq_sun').click(some_operation);
```

insted of this how can i write a for loop ?

```
for (var dx = 0; dx < days.length; dx ++ ) {
  $("#bm_freq_daily").click(some_operation);
}
```

This is not work, i just want to loop through all days[] when ever user clcik check box i loop the array and find which id is clicked.
Thanks in adavnce

Comment: assign a `class` to checkboxes and using `.each()` you can loop through them.

Comment: +1 @Bongs. OP may also add all his checkboxes inside a span with `id=daycheckboxes` then just select it `$("#daycheckboxes input[type='checkbox']")` or its equivalent `$("#daycheckboxes :checkbox")` as @tibo answered. The selector is larger, but saves you from having to add a class to each box manually. I guess a class may have better performance though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Find.You tag jquery so i try to put a sample in jquery.

```
var Days= $('#divDays').find('input.YourDayClass:checked');
                    $.each(Days, function(index, item) {
                        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
                           //What You try to Do
                        }
                    });
```

I think sample help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)method to iterate over it, by adding a css class to your checkboxes.

something like this

```
$('.yourCheckboxClass:checked').each(function(index, Elem)
{
  if($(this).id=="something")
   { //then do something 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#yourParent :checkbox').each(function(){
  $(this).click(some_operation);
});
```